# Cmake fails to build an executable

Tags: command-line, software-installation, compiling, cmake

Trying to build a program with Cmake Results in:

**me@ubuntu-20-04:~/Downloads/UxPlay/build$ cmake ..**

```
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
  No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
  to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/me/Downloads/UxPlay/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/me/Downloads/UxPlay/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log"
```

For a bit of clarification, I am trying to use https://github.com/antimof/UxPlay/blob/master/, and I followed the build instructions in the readme file

Comment: Please check here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/574961/why-is-there-no-cmake-cxx-compiler-could-be-found-and-how-to-solve I suspect you need build-essential.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, got it working.